# data-bind foreach not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to data-bind foreach but for some reason unable to spot the mistake.
Below is the snippet:-

```
<div class="row">
    <aside class="col-md-3">
        <div class="sidenav">
            <div>TEST</div>
            <div class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: wikiLinks">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
                   data-bind="text: articleText"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>
```

App.js file is the javascript file where wikiLinks variable value is assigned based on computed function.

```
    this.wikiLinks = ko.computed(function () {
    // load wikipedia data
    var cityStr= "bothell";
    var wikiUrl = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=' + cityStr + '&format=json&callback=wikiCallback';
    var wikiRequestTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        //$wikiElem.text("failed to get wikipedia resources");
    }, 8000);

    $.ajax({
        url: wikiUrl,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "callback",
        success: function( response ) {
            var articleList = response[1];
            articleList.forEach(function (article) {
                self.wikiListArray.push(new wikiObj(article));
            });
            return self.wikiListArray();
          //  clearTimeout(wikiRequestTimeout);
        }
    });
}, this);}

var wikiObj = function (data) {

 var self = this;
    this.articleText =  data;
    this.url =  'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + data;
}
```

Comment: You can't return values from the ajax success function.  Where would they even go?  The function passed in ko.computed would have finished and returned long before the ajax call completes.  You have to do all your assignment of new values and so on *in* the success function, or call another function passing it the new values (again, call that function from within success).

Comment: aha! Make sense. Thanks a lot for the guidance.I tweaked a bit and able to fetch the value from wikiListArray which is observable array.